# Calculate Cos a

Tags: trigonometry

angle a in radians is bigger och equal 0 and a is also smaller or equal pi/2

Calculate cos a if we know that sin a = 13/16

My answer is sqrt(87)/16
Is this correct and is this the correct way to write it?

Comment: $\cos a=\sqrt{1-\sin^2a}=\sqrt{1-13^2/16^2}=\sqrt{87}/16$

Answer (score 1):

When you know $\sin{a}$ and want to know $\cos{a}$ then you can use identity $$\sin^2{a} +\cos^2{a} = 1$$

By substituting $\sin{a}$ you are left with $\cos{a}=??$ and that's your answer.